# Mathematical Equality for Func<int, int>

Tags: c#, math, lambda, extension-methods

I have a `Sequence` type that implements `ISequence`. `ISequence` implements `IEnumerable<Element>` where `Element` is another custom type. Currently, my `Sequence` type stores the instructions for generating the N-th term of a sequence as a `Func<int, int>`. This is convenient because it allows me to call `NTerm(int n)` with a simple call to the `Func` and to create `Sequence`s with a lambda. I would like to avoid changing that approach.

I would like to check equality of two Sequence objects based on equality of the two `Func`s. I began browsing around, and there are a few posts that use `Expression`s to break down lambdas and `Func`s for equality, but I'm talking about mathematical equality.

> In other words, `x => 2 * x` should equal `c => c * 2`, along with any variations of mathematical expressions, such as Math.Pow or more involved operators. If I can get that to work, I can compare `Sequence`s for mathematical equality.

I tried to write my own extension method:

```
public static bool MathEquals(this Expression<Func<int, int>> f,
     Expression<Func<int, int>> g)
```

I'm not sure how to go from there. I have some basic defaults written:

```
if (ReferenceEquals (f, g)) return true;
if (f == null || g == null) return false;
if (f.NodeType != g.NodeType || f.Type != g.Type) return false;
```

but I need to check the mathematical equality of the two lambda expressions, i.e. the two `Func<int, int>`s. Can this be done? Does anyone have a solution? Do I need to change my approach for storing the N-th term formula? I'm against checking the output because sequences can be equal for some output and not all.

If I need to post any of the Sequence code, I will.

**UPDATE:** I've decided to mark Scott's answer as accepted. However, the work is not complete. Check out part two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689139/mathematical-equality-of-funcint-int-part-two-using-the-syntax-tree).

Comment: Do you also need `x * x` and `Math.Pow(x,2)` or `x * 2` and `x << 1` to be equal too? If so, this is not a easy problem to solve.

Comment: Well, you can compare outputs for every possible `int` input. That's the only way I can see. And then there's non-pure functions of course..

Comment: you can get the param for each expression,but there are too many case to check

Comment: `x * x` and `Math.Pow(x,2)` would be nice. The bit shifting isn't really necessary as I'm simply building a personal library where I plan to use standard math functions... @ScottChamberlain

Comment: However, if the only way to do it (well, the only easy way) would be to not include functions from the Math library, or function calls at all, I suppose I can accept that

Comment: The only "simple" thing you can do is to see if the sequences are equivalent member by member, and that's quoted because it involves a lot of recursion and edge cases. Even something like `1+a` vs `a+1` is insanely hard to realize they're equivalent. Not to mention `exp(ln(a))` and `a` or whatnot.

Comment: If you tightly define which operations are allowed, maybe it's possible.. you're basically asking for an algorithm to determine whether two computer programs are equivalent. This is not a simple problem.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, in fact it's provably impossible. It's one of the limits of computability. Crazy stuff really, it basically proves we can't build human-like intelligence with what we understand to be computer algorithms.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes, I suppose I hadn't considered that before. Darn impossible problems.

Comment: @Blindy, If we restricted ourselves to the five basic maths, +,-,*,/,%, would it be reasonable?

Comment: Can you short-circuit this comparison? How are you creating these Funcs? Can you compare the data you use to generate them or something?

Comment: Right now, I'm simply building them in the code: `var s = new Sequence(x => x * x);` and then doing stuff with it to check the implementation. I could conceivably compare inputs, for n from 0 -> Integer.MaxValue, but I'd run into overflow problems potentially

Comment: Ok, so if you need to compare Sequences for equality later, maybe you should do it differently. Give sequences a name that you can compare (`var s = new Sequence(x => x * x, "square");`) or set up some static Sequences that you refer to and compare with object.equals (`public static Sequence Square = new Sequence(x => x * x);`)

Comment: compile the 2 func to IL,and check if the IL same.is this a way?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I like your static Seqs suggestion, and I will definitely do that (sort of like Math.Pi). But what if I have something more complex? Like multiple math operators?

Comment: @chenZ not reliably, no.. it wouldn't work with `x => x * -1` and `x => x - (x * 2)` for example.

Comment: Well, you can still make static fields for them.. or give them names that you compare - just some kind of tag that lets you know whether two of them are the same. And obviously, never create two that are equivalent, but tagged/named differently.

Comment: can we say,if the result equal,the expression equal?

Comment: In other words, associate a piece of metadata with it that would be used to compare for equality. What if I cached the Sequences when they were created, and used some sort of private variable that is generated based on the sequence? That would still leave problems... Well I suppose for a personal library, I could at least handle it. I'm gonna look into what Scott wrote first though

Comment: @chenZ if you're asking is `x * -1` == `x - (x * 2)` then the answer is yes. We could compare all conceivable inputs and outputs. But that doesn't seem efficient

Comment: @BenKnoble yes, metadata, that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to your question, "How do I break apart a expression and evaulate it", and "How do I check that two expressions mean the same logical operation".

I don't know how to do the 2nd part, but I do know the first.

What you will need to do is create a [`ExpressionVisitor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor.aspx) and have it walk through each [`BinaryExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.binaryexpression.aspx) by overriding `VisitBinary` and building up a list of all operations.

```
public class OperationParser : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public OperationParser()
    {
        Expressions = new List<BinaryExpression>();
    }

    public List<BinaryExpression> Expressions { get; private set; }  

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
    {
        Expressions.Add(b);

        return base.VisitBinary(b);
    }
}
```

Then you would do

```
    Expression<Func<int, int>> expression1 = (x) => x + 2;
    Expression<Func<int, int>> expression2 = (y) => 2 + y;

    var parser1 = new OperationParser();
    parser1.Visit(expression1);

    var parser2 = new OperationParser();
    parser2.Visit(expression2);

    //TODO: write a way to compare parser1.Expressions to parser2.Expressions to see if they "mean the same thig"
```

You just need to fill in the TODO with "your second question"

Comment: Thanks for the help! This gives me at least some sort of starting point... I know how to get through the expressions. I'm curious, how does something like this handle an expression where order of operations matters? i.e., `2*x + 5`?

Comment: Could I build up a list of the Binary Operations and their operands, and check those against each other? Will this handle differences between variable names?

Comment: If you're asking how you get the order, it's from the binary expression structure. If you're asking how to store it, you'd be basically building an AST. This is deep compiler theory -- not for the faint of heart. Also there's no "variable names", you're in compiler land now, they're all memory locations.

Comment: @Blindy thanks for the warning and tips. I recognize I may have dived in over my head here, but I'm still going to try and see what comes out of it. Who knows. It might be fun.

Comment: That's what Van Gogh said, then he went nuts and cut off his own ear.

Comment: `2*x+5` will give you 2 expressions. The first will have a Left value of `(2*x)`, a Right value of `5` and a NodeType of `Add`. The 2nd will have a Left of `2` a Right of `x` and a NodeType of `Multiply`. If you do `ReferenceEquals(parser1.Expressions[0].Left, parser1.Expressions[1]);` you will get `true`. Using that information you will need to "build up order of operations" yourself, but all the info you need to do that is there. Put the code in a debugger and play with some inputs. You can put a breakpoint in `VisitBinary` and see what is going on.

Comment: Ok. I will post an update when I get something up and running.

Comment: I've got a super simple thing built, but it can't handle anything complex. I'd like it work recursively, but I'm just not sure how to proceed. Any advice?

Comment: I would remove your edit and ask a new question. Its a big enough topic that it could warrent it's own question.

Comment: If i do that, I'll likely accept your answer and update with a link to the new question.

Comment: Scott--I've updated the new question again with my current code. Ignoring the craziness of try catches, would you mind taking a look? I think the recursive solution is more possible with my current code, but I'm still not sure what the best way to handle it is.