# Mathematical Equality of Func<int, int> Part Two: Using the Syntax Tree

Tags: c#, math, lambda, expression

So, for those who have not been involved in my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31643934/mathematical-equality-for-funcint-int) on this topic, I have some C# types to represent `Sequence`s, like in math, and I store a formula for generating the nth-term as 
    Func NTerm;

Now, I would like to compare one `Sequence`'s nth-term formula to another for mathematical equality. I have determined that practically, this requires a limitation to five simple binary operators: +,-,/,*,%.

With tremendous help from Scott Chamberlain on the OP, I've managed to get here. I'm envisioning some kind of recursive solution, but I'm not quite sure where to proceed. Will keep chugging away. Currently, this handles single binary expressions like x + 5 or 7 * c, well, but doesn't deal with other cases. I think the idea is to start from the end of the List, since I think it parses with last operations at the top of the syntax tree and first ones at the bottom. I haven't yet done extensive testing for this method.

**UPDATE**

```
public sealed class LambdaParser : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public List<BinaryExpression> Expressions { get; } = new List<BinaryExpression> ();

    protected override Expression VisitBinary (BinaryExpression node)
    {
        Expressions.Add (node);

        return base.VisitBinary (node);
    }

    public bool MathEquals (LambdaParser g)
    {
        try
        {
            return MathEquals (Expressions, g.Expressions);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception ("MathEquals", e);
        }
    }

    public static bool MathEquals (List<BinaryExpression> f, List<BinaryExpression> g)
    {
        //handle simple cases
        if (ReferenceEquals (f, g))
            return true;
        if (f == null || g == null)
            return false;
        if (f.Count == 0 || g.Count == 0)
            return false;

        try
        {
            //handle single one element cases
            if (f.Count == 1 && g.Count == 1)
            {
                return MathEquals (f[0], g[0]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception ("MathEquals", e);
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException ("Math Equals");
    }

    static bool MathEquals (BinaryExpression f, BinaryExpression g)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals (f, g))
            return true;
        if (f == null || g == null)
            return false;
        if (f.NodeType != g.NodeType)
            return false;

        try
        {
            switch (f.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Add:
                case ExpressionType.Multiply:
                    return CompareCommutative (f, g);
                case ExpressionType.Subtract:
                case ExpressionType.Divide:
                case ExpressionType.Modulo:
                    return CompareNonCommutative (f, g);
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException ($"Math Equals {nameof(f)}: {f.NodeType}, {nameof(g)}: {g.NodeType}");
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception ($"MathEquals {nameof(f)}: {f.NodeType}, {nameof(g)}: {g.NodeType}", e);
        }
    }

    static bool IsParam (Expression f)
    {
        return f.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter;
    }

    static bool IsConstant (Expression f)
    {
        return f.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant;
    }

    static bool CompareCommutative (BinaryExpression f, BinaryExpression g)
    {
        bool left, right;
        try
        {
            //parse left f to left g and right g
            left = CompareParamOrConstant (f.Left, g.Left) || CompareParamOrConstant (f.Left, g.Right);
            //parse right f to left g and right g
            right = CompareParamOrConstant (f.Right, g.Left) || CompareParamOrConstant (f.Right, g.Right);

            return left && right;
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception ($"CompareCommutative {nameof(f)}: {f.NodeType}, {nameof(g)}: {g.NodeType}", e);
        }
    }

    static bool CompareNonCommutative (BinaryExpression f, BinaryExpression g)
    {
        bool left, right;
        try
        {
            //compare f left to g left
            left = CompareParamOrConstant (f.Left, g.Left);

            //compare f right to f right
            right = CompareParamOrConstant (f.Right, g.Right);
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception ($"CompareNonCommutative {nameof(f)}: {f.NodeType}, {nameof(g)}: {g.NodeType}", e);
        }

        return left && right;
    }

    static bool CompareParamOrConstant (Expression f, Expression g)
    {
        var ParamF = IsParam (f);
        var ConstantF = IsConstant (f);

        if (!(ParamF || ConstantF))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException ($"{nameof(f)} is neither a param or a constant", $"{nameof(f)}");
        }
        var ParamG = IsParam (g);
        var ConstantG = IsConstant (g);
        if (!(ParamG || ConstantG))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException ($"{nameof(g)} is neither a param or a constant", $"{nameof(g)}");
        }

        if (ParamF)
        {
            return ParamG;
        }
        if (ConstantF)
        {
            return ConstantG && (f as ConstantExpression).Value.Equals ((g as ConstantExpression).Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**END_UPDATE**

I updated the above code to reflect the changes made (mostly refactoring, but also a slightly different approach) after comments reminded me that I'd ignored the non-commutability of some operators.

How do I extend it for expressions with multiple operators of the five defined above? Instead of just 5 * x, something like 2 * x % 3 - x / 5.

Comment: Side note: since you need to deal with + and * (where a+b == b+a) I don't think you can get solution with any reasonable time. You'd have to start 2 matches on each + and * where arguments are not constants leading to O(2 ^ tree-height ) solution...

Comment: But its func<int, int> so only one should be param, and the others should be either vars or constants right?

Comment: ((2x+3)*(3x + 4) + (5x+6)*(7x + 8)) vs. ((8+7x)*(5x + 6) + (3x + 4)*(2x+3))

Comment: Fair. But on the same side, im not concerned too much about complexity. This is a personal project. If it aint perfect, oh well.

Comment: I just wanted to warn you that if you get O(n) solution it is *probably* wrong and missing a lot of cases.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the tip @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: Your first question described criteria that sound like you're evaluating extensional equality (do these things give the same result?) but the approach you're taking is intensional (compare the guts of these two things).  Restricting the operators will help, but to continue on this path will require implementing some serious CAS-style logic to normalize these expressions into some canonical form.  It's a big project.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I (finally) implemented the recursive solution: turns out all it took was a small refactoring and a simple one line method call anytime the expression I was parsing had subexpressions. Anyways, it passes your given case with no problem. But, I need to make it work for 6 + x - 5 == x + 1, which involves swapping the operands to produce a collapsable constant. Ideas?

Comment: Also, if you want, I'll update the code to reflect recent changes